# initiate Lightbox on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

On hover over images button appears
**HTML**

```
<div class="block-11 block-1">
        <div class="carousel-wrapper" id="carousel-1">
            <ul class="carousel clearfix">
                <li>
                    <a href="img/img_8.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-1" data-title="">
                        <img src="img/img_8.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">                       
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="img/img_9.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-1" data-title="">
                        <img src="img/img_9.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">                       
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="img/img_10.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-1" data-title="">
                        <img src="img/img_10.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">                      
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="img/img_8.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-1" data-title="">
                        <img src="img/img_8.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">                       
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="img/img_9.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-1" data-title="">
                        <img src="img/img_9.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">                       
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="img/img_10.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-1" data-title="">
                        <img src="img/img_10.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">                      
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="semitransparentoverlay">
                <input name="" type="button" value="Смотреть все фото" class="btn-1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1po0acv6/5/

Is there a way to do so that the images are downloaded to [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) when clicked on the button?

Answer (score 0):

The images will not get "downloaded" to lightbox on button click, you will have to add the images in the innerHTML of 'ul class="carousel clearfix"', I mean the HTML of 'li' including its children 'a' and 'img'. And then reinitialize the lightbox.

Like this:

```
jQuery('#button').click(function(){
    $('ul.carousel').html('<li>
                    <a href="img/img_10.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-1" data-title="">
                        <img src="img/img_10.jpg" alt="" width="646" height="350">                      
                    </a>
                </li>');
    //now code lightbox reinitialization, according to the library you are using
});
```

Best of luck :)